# Updating table column based on other table column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update table **cases_proceedings** but it will check some criteria for this in the other table **cases_attach_files** i.e.

```
SELECT cp.sno FROM cases_proceedings cp, cases_attach_files cf 
WHERE cp.`case_sno` = cf.`case_sno` AND cf.page_lbl_sno = 10 AND 
cp.`is_decided` = 0
```

But when i want to update the first table value and search the **sno** of the first table by using the **IN** operation with subquery like this:

```
UPDATE cases_proceedings 
     SET `is_decided` = 1 
WHERE sno IN(SELECT cp.sno FROM cases_proceedings cp, cases_attach_files cf 
WHERE cp.`case_sno` = cf.`case_sno` AND cf.page_lbl_sno = 10 AND 
cp.`is_decided` = 0);
```

It shows an error:

```
Error Code: 1093
You can't specify target table 'cases_proceedings' for update in FROM clause
```

i don't know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround here is to wrap the subquery in another subquery:

```
UPDATE cases_proceedings 
SET is_decided = 1 
WHERE sno IN
(
    SELECT sno
    FROM
    (
        SELECT cp.sno
        FROM cases_proceedings cp
        INNER JOIN cases_attach_files cf 
            ON cp.case_sno = cf.case_sno AND
               cf.page_lbl_sno = 10 AND
               cp.is_decided = 0
    ) t
);
```

The extra subquery works around the error because it forced MySQL to materialize the subquery containing the joins.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html), In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.

You can either wrap it in subquery or joining both tables as shown below:

```
UPDATE  cases_proceedings cp
        INNER JOIN cases_attach_files cf
            ON cp.case_sno = cf.case_sno
                AND cf.page_lbl_sno = 10 
                AND cp.is_decided = 0
SET     cp.is_decided = 1
```

Comment: i have tested your solution but it is taking very long time to complete....